# How to use encrypted password in Pentaho kettle transformations?

Tags: encryption, etl, pentaho, kettle

Any pointers on how can we use encrypted passwords in kettle transformations?

Comment: in what way are you wanting to "use" encrypted passwords? like for db passwords/configuration? or performing transformations on data containing encrypted passwords?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the **Symmetric Cryptography** step to encryption and decryption of data.
It all depends on what you are willing to achieve. But basically, if you know the type of encryption/decryption you need, the simplest **User Defined Java Class** could fit the bill.